# Tag MP3s using (user-specified) CDDB Disc ID

Tags: music, mp3, collection-manager, tags

I'm usually using Tag&Rename to tag MP3 files, however sometimes it doesn't calculate the Disc ID right (and it's not possible to specify a different one myself).

So if I have a Disc ID (and it exists in the DB, e.g. https://gnudb.org/gnudb/misc/ac102d0d) what tool can I use to automatically tag my songs according to this entry?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out [Mp3Tag](https://www.mp3tag.de/en/) does the job easily.